# React "Rendered fewer hooks than expected." when switching from Desktop to Mobile component everytime a useEffect hook is called in "homeSection"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

NOTE: I don't use media queries for switching from desktop to mobile , i have 2 different
components that get rendered depending on state of screenwidth if that has anything to do
with it

This is my homesection component that displays my age

If i change the timer to 10000 the application crashes after 10 seconds instead.

```
      function HomeSection() {
      const timer = 1000;
      const [myAge, setAge] = useState();

     //this useEffect hook gets called every second to update my age on the page if i remove 
     //this hook the switch from desktop to mobile works without giving any errors. but when 
     //i have this in i get "Rendered fewer hooks than expected" when i have switched from desktop to mobile and this hook is called
  
    useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setAge(getAge("2000/01/01"));
      console.log(" hello world");
     }, timer);
     return () => clearInterval(interval);
     }, []);
     ....
     //function to calculate age
    function getAge(date) {
    let months = " month ";
    let days = " day ";
    let hours = " hour ";
    let minutes = " minute ";
    let seconds = " second ";

    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(date);
    var YearDiff = today.getYear() - birthDate.getYear();
    var monthDiff = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (monthDiff > 1) {
      months = " months ";
    }
    var myDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
    var testing = myDay + today.getDate();
    var daysDiff = testing - birthDate.getDate();
    if (daysDiff > 1) {
      days = " days ";
     }
     var hoursDiff = today.getHours() - birthDate.getHours();
     if (hoursDiff > 1) {
      hours = " hours ";
     }
     var minDiff = today.getMinutes() - birthDate.getMinutes();
     if (minDiff > 1) {
      minutes = " minutes ";
     }
     var secDiff = today.getSeconds() - birthDate.getSeconds();
     if (secDiff > 1) {
       seconds = " seconds ";
     }

      var Age =
       YearDiff +
       " years " +
       monthDiff +
       months +
       daysDiff +
       days +
       hoursDiff +
       hours +
       minDiff +
       minutes +
       secDiff +
       seconds;
      return Age;
     }

     return (
       <div className="Section" id="homePage">
         <h1 className="helloworld">Hello World</h1>

          <h2> i am {myAge}</h2>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Show both mobile and desktop component. Also please format the question better, next time

Comment: I figured it out myself , in my mobile component i had used the "HomeSection" as an argument for a hook that sets the active title for which section i scrolled to.